# Segmentation Fault 11 on upgrading to Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an iOS project that as of yesterday was working perfectly.  Now I've updated to Xcode 7, bringing Swift 2.0 syntax.  I went through and resolved all the errors as suggested to use new syntax.  When I try to build, the build fails with a "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11".  This occurs on 4 different files.

The problem is, those four files didn't have any code that needed updating, and are quite simple files (on of them doesn't do anything but set a label to a property value).  What gives?

Comment: Debug time: Comment out code until the the failure disappears, narrow in on it until you get to a single statement and figure out the error.

Comment: I can comment out all the code in one of the troubled ViewControllers and still receive the same error.  I also tried commenting out all code in the AppDelegate, with no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The problem was that there were several errors that the compiler was not catching.  I got Xcode to find the errors by deleting a file, and then re-adding it.  This showed thirty-something more errors that, when fixed, caused my code to compile completely.

Comment: I have tried this but nothing happens. I have still this problem. Can you please give me some more advice. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried Cleaning and Analyzing to fish out any bugs?  Or restarting Xcode?

Comment: I have tried Cleaning, deleting derived data, Xcode restart, new target. Bud Analyzing I haven't tried. Can Analyzing show some additional bugs that building the app doesn't? I am not on my computer right now, so I will try it.

Comment: Analyzing doesn't find anything new. The same errors like after building.

Comment: Can you isolate it to certain files?

Comment: I am using Realm and converting whole workspace to Swift 2.0 cause some problems with included projects in it. So I change those projects to Pods and everything works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that simple typos could cause this, here is one

```
var myVar: Type = { return value }
```

The above is usually unidentified and even compiled sometimes but it also cause segmentation fault. simply removing the equal sign will fix it

```
var myVar: Type { return value }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set value to the label instead of label.text