# looped timer does not invalidate as instructed

Tags: swift, timer

I have built a "metal detector" kind of app that runs the "calculateDistance" function every 2 seconds, which calculates the distance in meters between the user location and a set marker, sets that to var globalDistance. Depending on if that distance, for simplicity, is >=10meters or <10meters, I am playing a scheduled timer that calls the "audioplayer" function, which plays a "beep" sound every 2 seconds (if distance>=10m) or every 0.5seconds (if distance <10m).

Problem is, the timers never invalidate as I instruct them to. So if I move from <10m to >10m with my device, the 0.5sec beeping continues. I do audioTimer.invalidate() to stop the timer running from previous iteration.

Any idea what I am doing wrong with my code? Many thanks

```
func calculateDistance {
    //here there is code that successfully calculates distance, every 2 seconds

    var timerSeconds = 0.0
    var audioTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: (timerSeconds), target: self, selector: #selector(googleMaps.audioPlayer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    if globalDistance > 10 { // globalDistance is where i set the distance every 2 seconds, with a timer fired on ViewDidLoad
        timerSeconds = 2
    }

    if globalDistance >= 0 && globalDistance <= 10 {
        timerSeconds = 0.5
    }

    audioTimer.invalidate()

    audioTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: (timerSeconds), target: self, selector: #selector(googleMaps.audioPlayer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    audioTimer.fire()
}

func audioPlayer(){
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to make sure there is no code path by which a `Timer` is started without stopping any prior one. You current code has a couple of paths by which an existing timer is not invalidated before starting the next one.

Furthermore, I would suggest that you only invalidate the old `Timer` if the new beep frequency is different than the old beep frequency. (Why invalidate the 2 second repeating beeping and start another timer if the old 2 second timer will do the job fine?)

So, this means that you will:

- pull both the `Timer` and the `TimeInterval` variables out of the function;
- only do the "new timer" process if it decides that the beep interval has changed; and
- make sure to always invalidate the old timer before creating a new one.

For example:

```
private var audioTimer: Timer?
private var beepInterval: TimeInterval?

private func updateBeepIntervalIfNeeded() {
    // here there is code that successfully calculates distance, called with whatever frequency you want

    let newBeepInterval: TimeInterval

    if globalDistance > 10 {
        newBeepInterval = 2
    } else if globalDistance >= 0 {
        newBeepInterval = 0.5
    } else {
        fatalError("less than 0?!")   // I'm inferring from your code that this cannot happen, but by using `let` above, Swift warned me that we had a path of execution we hadn't previously considered
    }

    if beepInterval != newBeepInterval {
        beepInterval = newBeepInterval
        audioTimer?.invalidate()
        audioTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: beepInterval!, target: self, selector: #selector(beep(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        audioTimer!.fire()
    }
}

@objc func beep(_ timer: Timer) {
    // perform beep here
}
```

Comment: You can use a switch to check ranges :)

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, but with two open ended ranges (`>10` and `<0`), you're then adding at least one `where` clause, at which point I think that a simple `if`-`else` is far more intuitive, IMHO. It's a matter of personal opinion, of course...

Comment: True. I have a prefix/postfix range operator defined for half open ranges ;p

Comment: Thank you sir - I will try this indeed you are right about checking for time interval change.. I have to mention that had tried pulling the timer out of the function but it gave me an uncomprehensible Segmentation Fault 11 error at runtime (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622093/segmentation-fault-11-on-upgrading-to-swift-2-0), hence why I tried (obviously erroneously) to set the timer in the function. Only a few weeks experience in coding here, still learning !

Comment: OK i just ran it, and again, as soon as i move the Timer and beep interval outside the function, as vars or private vars, again it fails to build i get a Command Failed due to : Segmentation Fault 11 on either case :/ It gives no console debugging, rather an incomprehensible page on the "issues" page. Any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: @Apneist - The problem is your `#selector`. Using a `target` of `self` and a `selector` of `#selector(googleMaps.audioPlayer)` doesn't quite make sense. But the timer code should be as above. I'd suggest you replace the beeping call with something like above.

Comment: This solved it - my understanding of selectors was too poor to get this issue without your advice. Really appreciate all the help, it works now!

Answer (score 1):

## The problem

There's several issues at hand here.

Firstly, I'd like to emphasis the difference between references and instances. When you call call an initializer, the system allocates a piece of memory for a new object, and gives you a *reference* to that memory, which is stored in whatever variable you assign it to. You can assign this reference to other variables, which will make copies of the reference. Each of these variable references the same original object. This object will continue to exist in memory until no more variables reference it.

In your case, you're not directly calling an initializer, but you're calling a static method which serves a similar purpose. A new object is allocated on your behalf, and you're given a reference, which you then assign to `audioTimer`. There's a catch to this, however. When you call `Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)`, the newly constructed timer is scheduled on the current run loop for you. The run loop is what's in charge of firing your timer at the right time. The consequence of this is that now the runloop is referencing your timer, preventing the timer object from being destroyed. Unless you invalidate your timer to unregister it from its runloop, the timer will continue to exist and fire forever, even after you delete your deference to it.

Now let's take a look at your code, with some explanation as to what's going on:

```
func calculateDistance {
    //here there is code that successfully calculates distance, every 2 seconds

    var timerSeconds = 0.0

    // 1) Initialize timer #1
    var audioTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: (timerSeconds), target: self, selector: #selector(googleMaps.audioPlayer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    if globalDistance > 10 { // globalDistance is where i set the distance every 2 seconds, with a timer fired on ViewDidLoad
        timerSeconds = 2
    }

    if globalDistance >= 0 && globalDistance <= 10 {
        timerSeconds = 0.5
    }

    // 2) Invalidate timer #1 (timer #1 is useless)
    audioTimer.invalidate()

    // 3) Initialize timer #1
    audioTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: (timerSeconds), target: self, selector: #selector(googleMaps.audioPlayer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    // 4) Fire timer #2 immediately
    audioTimer.fire()


} // At the end of this method body:
// - Timer #2 was never invalidated
// - audioTimer no longer references Timer #2, but:
// - Timer #2's runloop still references it, keeping it alive
// - Timer #2 is leaked
// ... and will continue firing forever.

func audioPlayer(){
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104)
}
```

We can see that a `Timer` is made in section one, which should fire off in `timerSeconds` seconds, 0. At section 2, that timer is invalidated. Even though the `Timer` was to fire off in 0 seconds, it is almost certain that its run loop hasn't gotten a chance to fire it yet. Thus, this time is created, never fires, and then invalidated. There's no reason for it to exist at all there.

Then, in section 3, Timer #2 is created and scheduled. it is manually fired at section 4, and then it's permanently leaked.

## The solution

You need an instance variable that holds reference to the timer. Without this, you have no way of invalidating the timer that has been already scheduled.

Secondly, you need to invalidate the timer at the appropriate time.

I suggest you take a look at Rob's answer for an example.

Comment: extremely useful explanation and solution, thank you sir

Comment: Have I answered your question?

Comment: Yes you have - really appreciate your time helping me on this - it worked now after your and Rob's suggestions :)

Comment: Could you please rate our answers and "accept" one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Youre creating a new, infinitely repeating, timer once, invalidate it immediately (why?), and then create another (why?), which is leaked forever.

Comment: Thanks for answering - I invalidate it because if i dont, then it will keep running forever from the previous loop (which could be either 2s or 0.5s intervals). I create the new one, coz every 2 seconds that i call the whole findDistance function (from another timer in ViewDidLoad), I want to check if distance is > 10m or <10m (from physical location of device), set interval seconds to 2s or 0.5s respectively, and play sound with its respective interval. Then every 2 seconds the whole thing resets again. It calls the right timer the first time, but if i move through 10m, the timers overlap.Thx

Comment: What your invalidation pertains to the timer you JUST created. The second timer your create is never invalidated (it's leaked) and it runs forever

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new timer,invalidating then creating a timer again.

You could try creating the timer,and when calling the audioPlayer function,checking for which sound to play depending on the value of the timerSeconds variable.

Comment: Thank you - I thought of that and that should work, but trying to understand why my code as is is not working, and how could my sound effect be achieved by using the same 1 sound, just repeat it faster or slower depending on distance. Reason is I want to add not 2 but 6 different "beeping" frequencies, depending on how close user is to target (so creating the sound effects would be much less time efficient)

Comment: Depending of how you are playing the sound you could use something like AVPlayer rate to define a playback rate using the same sound.

[https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1388846-rate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1388846-rate)

Comment: Thank you, i did not know about that, will check now. I tried with AVplayer too, but put a system sound for the example posted here for ease of illustration (has exactly same result in terms of frequency of output with my code)